# PyInstaller: Executable runs only in command line

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I successfully created a *pyinstaller* executable, but it refuses to open when I double click it. When I drag it into a terminal window, however, it works perfectly.

This happens regardless of whether I import modules or not.

How can I resolve this issue?

I'm using *pyinstaller 3.3.1, Python 2.7 and Ubuntu 18.04*.

Comment: Are you getting any error while double clicking the executable?

Comment: this does not make sense ...  it should definately just work ... try and open a command window and invoke it from the cmd prompt maybe you will see an error ... I assume double clicking other exe's works fine... anyway this is not a reproducible problem ... for us ... i guess you could provide a link to the binary you created .... but no many (if any will download some random exe)

Comment: I don't get any error when double clicking the executable, it just does nothing. I did try invoking it from the command line (as I already stated), and it worked perfectly, no errors. Even right clicking and hitting Run does nothing.